# Page refresh after the request is Done

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, window.location

I have a page with many checkboxes on it, I wrote a JS code that makes call to PHP page for each page, I want to refresh the page after the call has completed..
Here is my code

```
$(".matchFrnds").each(function(){  //For each CheckBox

        if($(this).is(':checked')){

            var sendData= $(this).val();

             $.post('Call to PHP Page',{sendData:sendData},function(data){


            window.location.reload();
                });
        }
        });
```

The problem is that the page reloads after completing few checboxes, so if there are 60 checkboxes, the  page reloads after making call for 10 checkboxes. I also changed the place for `window.location.reload();` but the results are same, I want that once the call for all the checkboxes is completed then it reloads.

Comment: why are you using ajax, which is meant to NOT reload the page, to perform a page reload? wouldn't a normal form with submit be good enough?

Comment: you have to set some flag for checking all the select box selected or not

Comment: @STTLCU I agree with your point, but I want to make transparent PHP processing on ajax and then reload/or may be just updating div. but in each case I need to know when the request is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really easy.
You just need to set a counter, and call `reload()` on the last one.
The idea would be to have another variable...

```
// Save the element to iterate in a variable
var matchFrnds = $(".matchFrnds"),
    //and save its length too
    length = matchFrnds.length;

//Iterate over it
matchFrnds.each(function() {
    // modify the counter
    --length;
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        // do your things
        $.post( ... , function(data) {
            //do what you need to do with the data...
            // ....
            // ....
        });
    }
    //and, if it's the last element
    if (!length) {
        // LAST ITERATION!
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

And that's it.

Comment: if u put the relaod outside of callback , the relaod will invoke before the last ajax call finish

Comment: You are right, but if I put it inside then, if the last checkbox is **not** checked, the reload will never happen. I figured that the question author would figure this out and implement the corresponding conditions in order to make it work properly. Should I change it, anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You can check how many calls you have finished then reload

```
var boxes = $(".matchFrnds:checked").length;
var calls = 0;
$(".matchFrnds").each(function(){  //For each CheckBox
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            var sendData= $(this).val();    
            $.post('Call to PHP Page',{sendData:sendData},function(data){

               calls++; 
               if(calls >= boxes) {    
                 window.location.reload();
               }

            });
        }
  });
```

Comment: (".matchFrnds:checked").length; returns different number tha n $(".matchFrnds:checked").length;

Comment: how come the length is different?

Comment: i missed `$` :) . Is it the answer wht you want ?

Comment: yaa.. without $ its just a string `"abcd".length //4`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42094/discussion-between-sarath-and-user1765876)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .ajaxStop-Event

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Comment: any detail, why he want to stop ajax?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this after complete your request:

```
location.reload();
```